# Thread.Sleep in Task.Run

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await, c#-5.0

I have been trying to get my head around C#'s new async/await and Task.Run functionality recently.  In doing so I wrote some simple test code that writes to the console so that I can see in what order things happen in, throwing in a Thread.Sleep here and there to make sure things really happens in the order I expected.

Here is one of my tests

```
[Test]
public void TaskRun()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Before");
    Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine(_terminator.IWillBeBack()));
    Console.WriteLine("After");
}
```

with the following Terminator class:

```
public class Terminator
{
    public string IWillBeBack()
    {
        return "I will be back";
    }
}
```

From this I expected the result to most likely be *Before*, *After*, and then *I will be back*.  This is indeed what happens.  Then I make a change to the IWillBeBack-method to allow it to sleep for 3 seconds.  The code for this:

```
public class Terminator
{
    public string IWillBeBack()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        return "I will be back";
    }
}
```

I expected the result to still be *Before*, *After*, and then after 3 seconds again *I will be back*.  This is not what happens though.  I instead get *Before* and *After*, but never *I will be back*.

Why is this?

When I debug it clearly goes through the code, sleeping and returning.  I don't need Thread.Sleep in this way in any production code, but I would like to have a vague understanding of why *I will be back* is not written to the console in the second case.

Comment: I'm a bit lazy today so I will just reference the answer. I wrote something on this a few days back that could help in understanding TPL+async/await: http://blog.tedd.no/2012/07/28/asyncawait-http-server-in-c/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your test is completing before it tries to print "I will be back". You're not doing anything to wait until that's finished. Depending on the test runner, however it's redirecting `Console.WriteLine` may have been disconnected as soon as the test has finished.

If you want to see it finish, change your test to:

```
[Test]
public void TaskRun()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Before");
    var task = Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine(_terminator.IWillBeBack()));
    Console.WriteLine("After");
    task.Wait();
}
```

Comment: That makes sense.  I ran your test and it works as expected now :)

Comment: Am I just "lucky" that it writes "I will be back" in the first case then (as I don't do anything to wait there either)?  In lucky I mean, it happens to be able to write in time to the Console before the test is completing.

Comment: @Halvard: Yup. It's possible that test tear-down has some "slightly costly" work to do which is giving your other thread the edge.

Comment: @Halvard: Please note that you should *only* use `Wait` in sample console applications. As a general rule, do not mix blocking and asynchronous code in production systems. You may want to read my [`async` intro](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and [followup post on `async` console programs](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-console-programs.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you use the MS Test framework in VS 2012 you can also write the test like this

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TaskRun()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Before");
    Task t = Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine(IWillBeBack()));
    Console.WriteLine("After");
    await t;
}

private string IWillBeBack()
{
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    return "I will be back";
}
```

Comment: I expected this to work when I saw your code, but when running your test I got *Before* and *After*, but not *I will be back*.  As far as I have understood the difference between task.Wait() and await task is that the first blocks and the second does not.  Could this be the reason yours does not work?  (By the way, I see the output in the the default test GUI window for VS 2012 and use the NUnit framework.  Could it be that I'm tricked by that?)

Comment: AFAIK, NUnit does not support `async` unit tests. I believe only MSTest and xUnit do right now.

Comment: UPDATE:  When the previous comment was written NUnit did not support `async` unit tests, but now it does.